# How to use docker run command in terminal?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I copy them to the terminal I get an error: **"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.**

I don't know why, should I separate them somehow separately or should the whole command go the first time?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add line breaks and your image name

```
docker run \
    --name example-chris \
    -v /home/Projects/example-chris/src/main/resources/application.properties:/config/application.properties \
    -v SOME_SOURCE:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt \
    --rm \
    -p 8081:8080 \
    SOME_IMAGE_NAME
```